# Dictionary Lookup with Integer, Type. Generic Accessing and setting of the key and value types

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, csla

CSLA .NET is a framework that my company uses heavily in most of our projects, so some of these constraints are forced by the framework itself and can't be changed. I'll do my best to indicate those constraints.

I have a set of about 50 classes that are all similar in the fact that they are basically a Dictionary (wrapped in a CSLA type) that provides a singleton instance of a lookup for use in various places in our program.

The classes are all roughly structured as follows

```
public class SomeLookup : Csla.NameValueListBase<Integer, SomeLookupPair>
{
    private static SomeLookup _list
    private SomeLookup
    {
        //DataPortal.Fetch Calls the DataPortal_Fetch and returns the <T>
        if (_list != null) { _list = DataPortal.Fetch<SomeLookup>; }
    }

    public static SomeLookup GetSomeLookup(Object criteria)
    {
        return new SomeLookup;
    } 

    public override void DataPortal_Fetch(Object criteria)
    {
        using(SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using(SqlClient.SqlCommand = new SqlClient.SqlCommand)
            {
                cm.Connection = cn;
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cm.CommandText = "getSomeLookup"

                using(var dr = new Csla.Data.SafeDataReader(cm.ExecuteReader)
                {
                    while(dr.Read)
                    {
                        //populates the interal nameValueList with lookup key/value pairs
                        Add(new NameValuePair(dr.GetInt32("Id"), 
                                              new SomeLookupPair { Code = dr.GetString("code"), 
                                                                   Description = dr.GetString("Description") });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SomeLookupPair
{
   public string Code {get; set;}
   public string Description {getl set;}
}
```

A table for a lookup is for example similar to

```
Table SomeLookUp
    ID int PK
    Code varchar(2)
    Description varchar(50)
```

So an object referencing the value from this lookup would be modeled in the database with just the ID field being stored so

```
Table SomeObject
   ID int PK
   SomeLookupId int FK
   .....
```

But in the class I would want to only display the Description or Code (Description for users, code for internal/business use)

My question is does handling this case where my class needs to access the object as follows

```
private integer _someLookupID  { get { //retrived from database and stored }; set { _someLookupId = value; }

public SomeLookupPair _someLookupPair { get { (SomeLookUp.GetSomeLookup)[_someLookupID] }; }

public void setSomeLookupID(SomeLookupPair pair)
{
   _someLookupId = (SomeLookup.GetSomeLookUp).Where(s => s.Value(pair)).Select(s => s.Key).SingleOrDefault
}
```

Feel like there is a better way to handle the setting of the value for the `SomeLookupID` where I can do it directly

Comment: could you actually create a Dictionary<int, string[]> and get at the NameValuePair / Key that way..

Comment: @DJKRAZE the reason for the Pair type is to actually have a clean way to access the objects in that need to be used. e.g. `SomeLookupPair.Code` vs `SomeLookupPair[0]` stronger OO and type referencing

Comment: I was thinking that you could do something more in the lines of foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in someLookup) but since you are wanting to do more of OO approach disregard. sorry

Comment: just looking at your code it appears that you are handling it in the Lamba with the SingleOrDefault in the event it can't find one or finds the first instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding you should write is as a single property:

```
public SomeLookupPair SomeLookupPair 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      (SomeLookUp.GetSomeLookup)[_someLookupID] }; 
   }
   set
   {
     _someLookupId = (SomeLookup.GetSomeLookUp).Where(s => s.Value(value)).Select(s => s.Key).SingleOrDefault;
   }
}
```

I fou want to get more performant (actually now you loop over all the values) you can refactor the SomeLookupPair and include ID (i think its designed for that your Lookup, cause now you dont use the performant access over the key!!!). 
Like that you get access to the selected id directly in the setter

```
public SomeLookupPair SomeLookupPair 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      (SomeLookUp.GetSomeLookup)[_someLookupID] }; 
   }
   set
   {
     if(value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
     _someLookupId = value.ID;
   }
}
```